# Add/Remove Material design tabs dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design

I have successfully implemented material design tabs but now I want to add a button so that user can add more tabs by pressing the button.How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/materialtest/vivz/slidenerd/activities/ActivityDynamicTabs.java

This is from a nice android tutorial by vivz slidenerd. This is what you were asking for. It has a button Add Tab clicking on which a tab will be added dynamically.